# Method code too large while building an ionic app on mac for android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an (cordova) ionic app. While building for android, I get:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

This is the error I get.

```
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:extractTryWithResourcesSupportJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebugException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.CoreLibraryRewriter$UnprefixingClassWriter.toByteArray(CoreLibraryRewriter.java:152)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:403)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/32.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/34.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/37.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/8.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/1 --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/24.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/29.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/16.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/44.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/11.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/49.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/40.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/3.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/28.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/30.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/mj/phonegap/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/mj/phonegap/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
37 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 35 up-to-date
Command finished with error code 1: /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
(node:68049) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.CoreLibraryRewriter$UnprefixingClassWriter.toByteArray(CoreLibraryRewriter.java:152)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:403)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/32.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/34.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/37.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/8.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/1 --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/24.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/29.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/16.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/44.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/11.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/49.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/40.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/3.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/28.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/30.jar --input /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --output /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/debug/classes.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/mj/phonegap/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/mj/phonegap/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar --min_sdk_version 16 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
```

I tried removing platform and adding it again. Did this multiple times - no progress. Still getting the  "Method code too large" error.

I have enough space on disk and ~1.5GB free memory is also available.

environment info is as below:

ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/mj/SW/atisundarnetwork/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
Node       : v8.9.4
npm        : 5.6.0 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

List of plugins:

```
$ cordova plugin ls
com-sarriaroman-photoviewer 1.1.10 "PhotoViewer"
com.razorpay.cordova 0.15.1 "RazorpayCheckout"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.9.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 0.12.1 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-freshchat 1.2.0 "Freshchat plugin for Phonegap"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic 3.0.0 "IonicCordova"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser 0.2.17 "ThemeableBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
cordova-support-google-services 1.0.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
mx.ferreyra.callnumber 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.2.5 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.3 "PushPlugin"
```

How to fix this? Will downgrading help?

Comment: can you post the list of native plugins you are using with the app?

Comment: @HasilT I just added the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgraded cordova-android for now. And this error was gone. cordova-android@6.3.4 is what I am working with now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin:

cordova-plugin-multidex

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-multidex
```

Using this with platform cordova-android@6.4.0